# Creating folder outside /var/www

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to create folder outside of my www folder where are stored my php scripts.

```
<?php

$subfolder = $_POST['subfolder'];
mkdir("../Norme/".$subfolder, 0755, true);

?>
```

If I chech inside Norme folder there are no new folders created.
Folder Norme is placed in /var/Norme.

If I change mkdir statement to:

```
mkdir("Norme/".$subfolder, 0755, true);
```

The script creates folder Norme and given subfolder inside /var/www

How to set different folder than www folder?

Answer (score 0):

Josef, Just change your code to:

> `mkdir("/var/Norme/".$subfolder, 0755, true);

It should work. And make sure that the folder **Norme** has proper rights/permissions to create the folder inside it.

Comment: Doesn't work. I've tried to other folder that has full premission for r/w. This server is connected to our local network and it's running Ubuntu os. We are accessing to folders like \\ServerName\SomeFolder. It is not real web server but there is folder called www where are my php scripts.